# converting json array to json object in Android studio

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am trying to create auto complete text view in android studio. I made web api in visual studio and I am returning json array with names of cities like this:

```
["Sarajevo","Mostar","Tuzla","Banja Luka","Zagreb","Split","Beograd"]
```

In android studio I created view model class.

```
public class GradoviVM{ 

public List<String> Naziv;

public List<String> Get()
{
    return Naziv;
}
}
```

In GradoviApi class I have implementation of function which is communicating with web api

```
public class GradoviApi {

public static void GetGradovi (final Context context, final MyRunnable<GradoviVM> onSuccess)
{
    String url = Config.url + "/api/gradovi";

    MyVolley.get(url, GradoviVM.class, new Response.Listener<GradoviVM>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(GradoviVM response) {
            onSuccess.run(response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MyApp.getContext(), "Greška u komunikaciji sa serverom: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

And this is the code from activity where auto complete text view is

```
public class PretragaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pretraga);

    GradoviApi.GetGradovi(this, new MyRunnable<GradoviVM>() {
        @Override
        public void run(GradoviVM result) {

        }

    });
    GradoviVM gradovi = new GradoviVM();
    List<String> nazivi = gradovi.Get();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, nazivi);
    AutoCompleteTextView actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.mjestoPolaskaACTV);
    actv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
};
```

Error says that expected type is Begin object but was Begin array.

Answer (score 0):

Your model class is assuming there's a `Naziv` property in the json it's being mapped to.  You should be able to update your code to do something like:

```
MyVolley.get(url, GradoviVM.class, new Response.Listener<ArrayList<String>>()
```